# Shopify Liquid Contact Form Send to Multiple Emails

Tags: forms, shopify, liquid

I'd like to manually add (in the code) an additional email address for my Shopify contact form data to be sent to. I'm not very familiar with Liquid, so I'm having trouble determining if it's even possible.

```
{% form 'contact' %}

    {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
      <p class="note form-success">
        {{ 'contact.form.post_success' | t }}
      </p>
    {% endif %}

    {{ form.errors | default_errors }}

    {% assign name_attr = 'contact.form.name' | t | handle %}
    <label for="ContactFormName" class="label--hidden">{{ 'contact.form.name' | t }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="ContactFormName" name="contact[{{ name_attr }}]" placeholder="{{ 'contact.form.name' | t }}" autocapitalize="words" value="{% if form[name_attr] %}{{ form[name_attr] }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.name }}{% endif %}">

    <label for="ContactFormEmail" class="label--hidden">{{ 'contact.form.email' | t }}</label>
    <input type="email" id="ContactFormEmail" name="contact[email]" placeholder="{{ 'contact.form.email' | t }}" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" value="{% if form.email %}{{ form.email }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}">
  
    <label for="ContactFormMessage" class="label--hidden">{{ 'contact.form.message' | t }}</label>
    <textarea rows="10" id="ContactFormMessage" name="contact[body]" placeholder="{{ 'contact.form.message' | t }}">{% if form.body %}{{ form.body }}{% endif %}</textarea>

    <input type="submit" class="btn right" value="{{ 'contact.form.send' | t }}">

{% endform %}
```

The form tag in liquid creates this form tag HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="/contact#contact_form" id="contact_form" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="contact-form">
```

I'm not sure what's going on in the background to get this data sent via email, but is it possible to add another email recipient?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, formatted forms are sent to email set in store admin.
However you might set up a Gmail address and then define rules in Gmail to automatically forward mails to other mail addresses.